# Leibniz Rule Check: $h(x)=\int_{0}^{2x - 1} f(t) dt$

Tags: calculus

**Question**

Let $f$ be the function shown below over the domain $[0, 6]$.

[image: mth]

Let $h(x) = \int_{0}^{2x - 1} f(t) dt$.

1. Determine domain of $h(x)$
2. Find $h'(5/2)$
3. At what $x$ is $h(x)$ a maximum?

**My Work**

$x = \frac{t + 1}{2}$

Domain: $x \in \left[ \frac{1}{2}, \frac{7}{2}\right]$

---

Do the first-derivative test:

$h'(x) = 2f(2x - 1)$

$h'\left( \frac{5}{2} \right) = 2f\left( 2\frac{5}{2} - 1\right) = 2f(4) = 2(0) = 0$

---

As we can see from $f(t)$, above, there is a relative maximum at $t = 5$. In terms of $x$ that would be:

$x = \frac{t + 1}{2} = \frac{6}{2} = 3$

I'm pretty sure that #1 and #2 are correct - but am I okay for #3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost the usual "set derivative equal to $0$" procedure of the usual max/min problem. We have $f(2x-1)=0$ when $2x-1=4$.

Let's think about the problem geometrically. We are integrating $f(t)$ from $0$ to "somewhere." The function $f$ is positive until $t=4$, then it is negative. So the (signed) area up to "somewhere" grows until $f(t)$ becomes negative, and then it starts shrinking. The shrinking starts at $t=4$.

Comment: Well, you also have to check the end points since it is a closed interval. But in this case that wouldn't change the answer. It would matter, however, if you were to, say, find the minimum of h(x).

Comment: @limac246: The geometry of the situation rules out the endpoints. It shows that the absolute **minimum** occurs at the beginning, since the first (positive) arch has much bigger area than the second arch.

Comment: That makes sense - so at $x = 2.5$ there is a relative maximum.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Absolute maximum too.